# JsonReader class not found

Tags: java, gson

It's my first time trying to access a google sheet using java. I followed the google tutorial regarding how to read and write. Now, I am facing a problem when running the code snippet provided by google [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java#set_up_the_sample).

The error follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader
        at com.google.api.client.json.gson@1.42.1/com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory.createJsonParser(GsonFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.api.client@1.42.1/com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory.fromReader(JsonFactory.java:229)
        at google.api.client@2.0.0/com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.load(GoogleClientSecrets.java:190)
        at com.egensolve.edt.edt@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.egensolve.edt.edt.SheetController.getCredentials(SheetController.java:39)
        at com.egensolve.edt.edt@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.egensolve.edt.edt.SheetController.main(SheetController.java:52)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 5 more
    
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader
```

The code doesn't show any error regarding Gson package, so I am lost.

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'com.egensolve.EDT'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.9.2'
}

sourceCompatibility = '18'
targetCompatibility = '18'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.egensolve.edt.edt'
    mainClass = 'com.egensolve.edt.edt.Main'
}

javafx {
    version = '18.0.2'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.2')
    implementation('com.dlsc.formsfx:formsfx-core:11.6.0') {
        exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
    }
    implementation (group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7')
    implementation ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:2.0.0')
    implementation ('com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.34.1')
    implementation ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev20220927-2.0.0')
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
```

Comment: did you add the mentioned dependencies to build.gradle? Gson is a transitive dependency of the google api client and should be brought into your project via a dependency of your project to the google api client.

Comment: Could you try using a newer Gson version in your `build.gradle` file, for example 2.10.1? And does your project have a `module-info.java` file? In that case you might have to add `requires com.google.gson;` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clone the entire project and test it one more time, don't forget to copy the json.

```
git clone git@github.com:googleworkspace/java-samples.git
cd java-samples/sheets/quickstart
gradle run
```

It works fine on my end!

Comment: there is something I want to make sure I am doing right, it says to replace my build.gradle with the code it gives me, is that a must or can I just add the lines that implements the google drive api and so on; because I am using javafx and when I replace the code, it can't find javafx

Comment: I added the build.gradle so you can check what I am doing, I also noticed that adding the gson implementation or not does not affect the result. so does it mean it can't identify the implementation at all